# How to make the text in a text area begin slightly lower?

Tags: html, css

My current code is simply:

```
<textarea
class="form-field-textarea"
id="contact_message"
name="contact[message]"
value=""></textarea>
```

Basically I am looking to move the text inside the container downwards. Right now it's too high and it interferes with my label. How can I do this?

Comment: do you mean push the text downwards inside its container?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you clarify?

Comment: @UdenduAbasili Correct

Comment: @RifatBinReza Sure. I have a label located in the top right of my text area. When a user types in the text area, the label goes over their typed text. Rather than moving the label further up, I wish to move the text inside down (not the whole container).

Comment: I got what you're saying. Can you show us with a sample code so that it's easy for us to solve it

Comment: `.form-field-textarea\} { padding-top: 50px; }` in your CSS file (note that you have added an closing curly bracket in your class name that I've escaped above)?

Comment: @RifatBinReza what do you mean by that? I thought I already included sample code?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Just tried that and it didn't do anything. And yes, my bad, that closing curly bracket was leftover from some liquid code.

Comment: Your text area doesn't really help with anything as it doesn't explain the problem with your style and label

Comment: @RifatBinReza Forget the label then. Imagine a text area with no style and label. I simply want to move the text downwards without moving the container. Like adjusting the top padding.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pwny0u9t/ This fiddle demonstrates the text starting lower in the textarea, which is what you said you wanted... If that's not what you want, [edit] your question to explain what you want more clearly.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Alright, thanks. For some reason mine doesn't do that. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: "*I simply want to move the text downwards without moving the container. Like adjusting the **top padding***" <-- yes

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might have some other CSS and HTML that are affecting your textarea. Without seeing more, this is usually how I manipulate the spacing of a textarea.

This answer may change once more is revealed about the structure regarding the label.

```css
textarea{
padding-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<textarea
class="form-field-textarea"
id="contact_message"
name="contact[message]">Hello I am some content.</textarea>
```